# Ending WebRTC video call between two peers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, p2p

I've set up a video chat between two peers using `WebRTC`. I would like to allow a peer to end the chat and for the other peer to know that the chat was ended. Once the chat ends, some code needs to be executed for both peers. The `PeerConnection` object has a `removeStream()` method which should trigger the `onremovestream()` listener. This would be perfect for my use case, however, before onremovestream() is called there needs to be a re-negotiation (offer/answer) between the peers. For my case this seems odd. Why would I re-negotiate only to disconnect? Shouldn't the PeerConnection object realize no stream is coming from the other user? **My question:** how can I end a PeerConnection and alert the other user?

Comment: The reason it is being renegotiated is for the case when you have more than one stream. You can just close the connection if you only have one media stream in the connection.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent how would one peer know when the other closed the stream in my case? Is there a listener?

Comment: How are the peers communicating? That is, are they capable of sending messages to each other? Or can they only communicate with the sever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply close the connection. The other peer can listen for the signal `oniceconnectionstatechange` and the state of `disconnected` means that your peer has closed the connection/is no longer available. If I were you, I would do a timeout before closing as this state could be because of a flaky network connection. [MDN has some good info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection.iceConnectionState)

Or, you could keep track of connections with your signalling server and signal the peers when somebody leaves. Either way should work.

Comment: I was thinking of using the signaling channel to alert the other user. I'll take a look into onicconnectionstatechange. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Open a datachannel and use it to say "I'm done"; when one side gets "I'm done" it says "ok, you're done".  To be totally safe and have both sides know the call is ending before it really disconnects, use a 3-way handshake over datachannels to end the call (and you can change the media to black/silence immediately by setting track.enabled = false for the audio and video tracks)