# Ending Call not on Android Devices WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc

I am working on call ending between two peers when they are connected and if either wants to end the call, the client is supposed to send the signal to the server. User A's activity ends and resume to showing a list of users online but rather it shows a white screen when User A tries to end the call. I have called finish()on onRemoveRemoteStream() because after removing peer, this overridden method will send the signal to the remote peer to end the stream from User B's side aswell. However, my application crashed after User B's resume to the user list activity and then User A's app crashes aswell. The error comes like the following:

> /com.app.webrtcdemo E/rtc: #
>       # Fatal error in ../../talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc, line 940
>       # Check failed: 0 == (reinterpret_cast
> (j_p))->Release() (0 vs. 1)
>       # Unexpected refcount.
>       #
>   /com.app.webrtcdemo A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13701 (.app.webrtcdemo)

Comment: kindly read this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat

Comment: thankyou and for now, this error CPU usage is fine. The problem is the first error from peerconnection jni.

Comment: I have found one link for my problem as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287844/ending-webrtc-video-call-between-two-peers. However, it does help much since I want to send a signal to my signaling server that user A has ended the call so dispose off the users from peers and send signal to user B to end the remote session aswell.